# Error when creating Woocommerce "Products per Page" dropdown. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

I've added the following to my site to allow a dropdown menu to select the amount of products per page.

```
if (!function_exists('tf_display_products_per_page_dropdown_on_shop')) :
 
    add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'tf_display_products_per_page_dropdown_on_shop', 25);
 
    function tf_display_products_per_page_dropdown_on_shop() {
         
        $perPage = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
 
        $perPagesOptions = array(
            ''    => 'Posts Per Page',
            '12'  => 'Show 12 Products',
            '20'  => 'Show 20 Products',
            '50'  => 'Show 50 Products',
            '100'  => 'Show 100 Products',
            '-1'  => 'Show All Products'
        );
 
        echo '<div class="woocommerce-perpage" style="float:right">';
            echo '<select onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">';
 
            foreach ($perPagesOptions as $value => $label) :
 
                echo "<option " . selected($perPage, $value) . " value='?perpage=$value'>$label</option>";
 
            endforeach;
 
            echo '</select>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
 
endif;

if (!function_exists('tf_change_products_query_for_page')) :
 
    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'tf_change_products_query_for_page');
 
    function tf_change_products_query_for_page($query) {
 
        $perPage = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
 
        if ( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive('product') ) :
            $query->set('posts_per_page', $perPage);
        endif;
    }
 
endif;
```

This isn't working. Product remains at default count, and is producing the error

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number ?perpage=25

in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because the value you're providing within each option is "?perpage=". Try update your select code to this.

```
echo '<select name="perpage" onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">';

foreach ($perPagesOptions as $value => $label) :
   echo "<option " . selected($perPage, $value) . " value='$value'>$label</option>";
endforeach;

echo '</select>';
```